# lambda in python saying list object is not callable

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter

```
my_list = [3, 4, 7, 2, 9, 170]

f = filter(lambda x: x%2==0, my_list)

g = f(my_list)
```

Having an issue with this lambda which kicks off a "list object is not callable" error. This is a very straightforward lambda so i'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: But the result of filter is (in Python-2.x) a list. Not a filter, you did the filtering **on a list**.

Comment: `f` is a list and you are calling it like if it was a function `f(my_list)`

Comment: I don't think you need to pass your list to lambda ```f``` on the second pass - ```f``` should just contain the filtered list you are looking for.

Comment: `f = lambda my_list : filter(lambda x: x%2==0, my_list)`

Comment: @ISOmetric here `f` is not a lambda, it's a list, and that's actually the whole point ;)

Comment: Is this true in python 3 as well? I just saw a lot of lambda's being called f(my_list) what does that do? or would the equivalent of that be: lambda x: x%2==0, and it still required a list passed to it?

Comment: @a1letterword you'd get a `TypeError: 'filter' object is not callable`

Comment: @a1letterword: the lambda is the *filter criterion*, it is not the *filter* itself. A filter takes as input an iterable, and - based on the filter criterion - yields the elements that satisfy that criterion.

Answer (score 7):

You perhaps think that `f` is a **filter**, it is not, `f` is the **result of a filtering** on `my_list`. That is a `list` in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), and a generator (a `filter` object) in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x).

You can however construct a filter, for instance by using the `partial` function of `functools`, like:

```
from functools import partial

f = partial(filter,lambda x : x % 2 == 0) # construct a "filter"

g = f(my_list) # filter my_list
```

Comment: So what is going on in this case? I've been stuck on a problem for an hour or two and can't seem to figure out if the error is on my end.                                                # Complete the function below.

f = lambda my_list: x%2==0, my_list                                                              if '<lambda>' not in f.__name__:
    raise ValueError('Please write a lambda function')

my_list = json.loads(sys.stdin.readline())
for x in f(my_list):
    print(x)

Comment: and i can only edit the function lambda. for some reason i continuously get an error that says my_list is not defined